# Zeroaxis not appearing on Heatmap in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to display the zero axes on a heatmap. My code is as follows:-

```
set term wxt
set size 0.9,0.9
set border lw 2
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set cbrange [0:1]
set xrange[-180:180]
set yrange[-180:180]
set cbrange[0:0.002]
set xtics center out 60
set ytics out 60
set xtics font ':Bold'
set ytics font ':Bold'
set xlabel "{/:Bold x}"
set ylabel "{/:Bold y}"
set zeroaxis lt -1 lw 2 
plot 'data.txt' u 1:2:3 w image notitle
```

The zero axes are appearing behind the heatmap. The resultant plot is shown below. How can I display it on the heatmap?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is controlled by the front/back status of the grid lines.  Note that when you set this to "front" it has the side effect of enabling the x and y grid lines by default, so you probably want to turn them off again:

```
set grid front nox noy
```